# How to insert part of a vector into a matrix, from a for loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, indexing

I have two data sets of 180000 samples, sampled at 100 Hz. I use two for loops to pick out a window of data from the first set and correlate that window with the entire second data set. A sliding window correlation if you will. Then I pick out a new window from the first data set and correlate that on the entire second dataset. If there is a correlation above a certain limit between two windows of data, I want to insert that data in a matrix. One matrix for windows from the first data set and a second matrix for the second data set. The matrix part is giving me a hard time. Thank you for your help.

```
close all; clear all;

win=6000;
jump=6000;

W=load('TULEG-filter.mat');
a=W.data_filtreret_SI;
U=load('KULLO-filter.mat');
b=U.data_filtreret_SI;
a1=[a; zeros(1,win)'];
b1=[b; zeros(1,win)'];

tic
for j=1:jump:numel(a)
    sig1=a1(j:(win+j-1));
    %env_sig1=envelope(sig1,1000,'peak');
   
for i=1:jump:numel(b)
    sig2=b1(i:(win+i-1));
    %env_sig2=envelope(sig2,1000,'peak');
   
   cor=corrcoef(sig1,sig2);
   c(i)=cor(1,2);
   
   
   
   if c(i)>=0.8
       matrix1(i,:)=sig1;       
       matrix2(i,:)=sig2;   
   end
end
end
toc

matrix1=matrix1(~all(matrix1==0,2),:);
matrix2=matrix2(~all(matrix2==0,2),:);
```

Comment: The code looks pretty good. Did you want `matrix_1` and `matrix_2` to be column/row vectors?

Comment: "giving me a hard time" is not clear. what is the question here?

Comment: I want each window to be a row in the matrix. However for each new j it overwrites the old rows in the matrix. The code works for the first j and all i, but then starts to overwrite.

Comment: I have solved it. Now the j loop dosn't overwrite the matrix. I don't know how to upload the new code.